# git hangs on fetch after authentication

Tags: git, clone

This is my git config file contents:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0 
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
  url = http://myusername:mypassword@192.168.1.30/git/dpi.phorcys.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/develop
```

The problem that I face from yesterday is that I can't fetch one of my branches anymore!

```
ebrahim@ubuntu:~/phorcys/dpi.phorcys$ git fetch origin master
From http://192.168.1.30/git/dpi.phorcys
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
ebrahim@ubuntu:~/phorcys/dpi.phorcys$ git fetch origin develop
^C
ebrahim@ubuntu:~/phorcys/dpi.phorcys$
```

As you see above, I successfully fetched `master`, but for `develop` branch, the git stuck there and I need to hist *ctrl + c*.

I captured the network traffic while trying to fetch my develop branch, and you can see the corresponding network traffic below:

```
GET /git/dpi.phorcys.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.30
User-Agent: git/2.9.3
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:58:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 344
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=900
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Peygir"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Peygir

..........u..K.0....W.{q.M.*2!..Vq0uh}.1k.5.%5I.....M.E......./.l.</...<..+X....s.]
.,.{!.....x"D.4......e.JS.Ml0.NR.u.v.|.h......G-.q.IqP.....I....b.........C..F.u..2.=.ZE.]..GP'.j..TUa.4..]...F.    .!...........m. ...wv.*.@
...c.[~....U!.....p..g...d...`.#tV..QY
...N...
..X...K..Ix....\..VU5....`...Qv....h..6......*......4...@9.....ob?........GET /git/dpi.phorcys.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.30
Authorization: Basic ZS5naGFzZW1pOmVicmFoaW1naGFzZW1p
User-Agent: git/2.9.3
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:58:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=900
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Server: Peygir

1e
001e# service=git-upload-pack

4
0000
a3
00a3075559c660457bcddb7b4ad038d1562f10f260ac HEAD.multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done

40
0040916af59346d53d7958c4d2f83bde80911b4bd578 refs/heads/develop

3f
003f075559c660457bcddb7b4ad038d1562f10f260ac refs/heads/master

4
0000
0

POST /git/dpi.phorcys.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.30
Authorization: Basic ZS5naGFzZW1pOmVicmFoaW1naGFzZW1p
User-Agent: git/2.9.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Length: 224

006fwant 075559c660457bcddb7b4ad038d1562f10f260ac multi_ack_detailed no-done side-band-64k thin-pack ofs-delta
0032want 916af59346d53d7958c4d2f83bde80911b4bd578
0032want 075559c660457bcddb7b4ad038d1562f10f260ac
00000009done
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:58:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=900
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Server: Peygir
```

I neither can `clone` nor can `pull` from the repository.

When I change the password or the repository address, I receive meaningful errors though.

Comment: what git version you are using ?

Comment: git version 2.9.3

Comment: Please update the Git Version to 2.13.0 once, and check again. Using `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @LuFFy I updated the git client and tried again to fetch the develop branch. It returns `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Run this command `git remote add origin http://myusername:mypassword@192.168.1.30/git/dpi.phorcys.git` and try again please

Comment: @LuFFy Tried it and nothing changed. I also changed the http post buffer size and still nothing changed.

Comment: Please try `git remote add origin http://myusername:mypassword@192.168.1.30/git/dpi.phorcys` and try again to pull

Comment: I hope you are aceesible for this folder `192.168.1.30/git/dpi.phorcys`